# Is there a better way to check if a pid input is all numbers?

Tags: c

So I have this program that takes in PID input and a character.

```
$ ./transmit 1111 a
```

My question is. If it were

```
$ ./transmit 111a x
```

since PID are all numbers I'd need to catch that.

given:

```
char *a[] = {"./transmit", "111a", "x"};
```

how would I check if "111a" is numeric only? isdigit only works if it's a character. Do I have to loop through the entire input?

Comment: You may be interested in `strtol`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *err;
unsigned long pid = strtoul(argv[1], &err, 10);

if (*err || err == argv[1])
    error();

if ((pid_t)pid != pid || (pid_t)pid <= 0)
    error();
```

When you are really pedantic, you can check for `ULONG_MAX` and `errno == ERANGE` too, but because `pid_t` is smaller than `unsigned long`, this will be catched by the second check already.

Comment: Minor: Unclear why use `strtoul()`?  Is not `pid_t` a signed integer type?

Comment: negative values (and `0`) for `pid_t` do no represent real pids, but are used for special purposes only (error signaling, group ids in `waitpid()`.

Comment: This code does not properly check for negative values.  `(pid_t)pid != pid` serves no purpose.  By using `strtol()`, negative values can be detected, unlike  `strtoul()`. 
 Values outside the the signed range of `pid_t` are also problematic.  Converting a unsigned to a out of range signed (`pid_t)pid`) is ID behavior.  It would be better full range detection to not allow any value to a `pid_t` that is not in range.

Comment: Example, if `argv[1] == "-1"` and `pid_t` same width as `unsigned long/long`: `strtoul()` returns `ULONG_MAX` and `(pid_t)pid != pid`  is typically false - failing to detect negative values.  By converting to `strtol()`, a negative input string could be  detected and not pass negative values nor values > `LONG_MAX` like this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use the [strspn()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strspn.htm) function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc > 1) {
        if (argv[1][strspn(argv[1], "0123456789")] == '\0') {
            puts("Yes, the first command line argument is all numeric.");
        }
        else {
            puts("No, the first command line argument is not all numeric.");
        }
    }
    else {
        puts("Please provide an argument on the command line");
    }
    return 0;
}
```